# Wrong test executed first in Selenium TestNG

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

In the below script I want to run the Test 'Login' first and then the 'CreateCompany'. But whenever I try to run the script always the control goes to the 'CreateCompany' test at first. And since the user is not already logged in the script execution fails. Please someone tell me what is wrong with the script below.

```
package MyPackage;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import MyPackage.PageObjects.CompanyListing;
import MyPackage.PageObjects.LoginPage;

public class SetUpCompany {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public String BaseURL=LoginPage.BaseURL();
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup()  {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
       }  
    //public static WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    @Test(dataProvider="UserData")
    void Login(String username, String password, String usertype){      
        //dr.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if(usertype.equals("SuperAdmin")){          
            String LoginURL=BaseURL+"/Manage";
            driver.get(LoginURL);
            LoginPage.UsernameBox(driver).sendKeys(username);
            LoginPage.PasswordBox(driver).sendKeys(password);
            LoginPage.LoginButton(driver).click();
            //System.out.println("Hello Super admin!");
        }

    }
    @Test(dataProvider="CompanyData")
    void CreateCompany(String FrstNm, String LastNm, String CmpnyNm, String Email, String Phone, String Cell, String Web){
        System.out.println("I'm here");
        String ManageCompanyURL=BaseURL+"/Manage/Company";
        driver.get(ManageCompanyURL);
        CompanyListing.AddCmpnyBtn(driver).click();
    }
    @DataProvider(name="UserData")
    public Object[][] loginData() {
        Object[][] LoginArray = DataReader.getExcelData("E:/DataBase.xls","LoginData");
        return LoginArray;
    }
    @DataProvider(name="CompanyData")
    public Object[][] CompanyInfo() {
        Object[][] CompanyArray = DataReader.getExcelData("E:/DataBase.xls","CompanyInfo");
        return CompanyArray;
    }
    @AfterClass
    public static void teardown()  {
    driver.close();
    driver.quit();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try writing priorities in your `@Test` annotations in TestNG to set the execution sequence. Here's how to do it -

```
@Test(priority=1, dataProvider="UserData")
void Login(String username, String password, String usertype){
    //Your login code
}
@Test(priority=2, dataProvider="CompanyData")
void CreateCompany(String FrstNm, String LastNm, String CmpnyNm, String Email, String Phone, String Cell, String Web){
    //Your CreateCompany code
}
```

[More info on priorities in TestNG](http://seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/testng-test-case-priority). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is dependent tests where CreateCompany is dependent upon login test.
You should be using dependsOnMethods.  Read more [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#dependencies-with-annotations)